# Get anaconda root directory

Tags: environment-variables, python3, paths, anaconda

l'm looking to get my anaconda root directory. so l run :

```
which anaconda3
```

l got

```
/root/anaconda3/bin/anaconda
```

Is that my anaconda root directory ?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43635283/1081936) on multiple sites of the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Why, for the love of god, did you install software in /root? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117132/change-anaconda-ipython-main-directory/34582168 there should be a settings option to show you the path for anaconda (and you can change it there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the *root* directory will probably be `/root/anaconda3/`. That's where `anaconda` was installed so that is probably (I don't really know since you haven't given any information) what you mean by "root directory".

Comment: l need it for the followinf : export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=[anaconda root directory] . look at the in the bottom  install optional dependencies https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch

Comment: @vincent OK, but that sort of thing needs to be in your question. Since you accepted, I assume this worked, so never mind. But next time, please include all relevant details in your question.